# Flutter Bug in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, build.gradle

[image: Console]
Error while Building Flutter Project.
I have upgraded `gradle-version` and also reinstalled Android Studio.

Comment: Please post errors as text, people can’t search for content in images

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept Android SDK agreement. Execute this command:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Enjoy!